# Workflow task - complete without edit?

Tags: workflow, tasks, task-list

Is it possible to assign a task to a user without them having to hit "Edit" to select an option and hit submit?

[image]

this is what it currently looks like, and it allows a user to rename the task and is just kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Open designer and double click on the initiation form.

It will open the form in InfoPath. Disable the fields and save publish the form.